# SocketException: Too many open files in AWS Lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-mvc, aws-lambda, geocoding

This Java method is part of the executed code within an AWS Lambda function:

```
private static String getLocationIQAddress(double lat, double lng, boolean cached) {
    lat = truncate(lat);
    lng = truncate(lng);

    MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor ri = new LoggingRequestInterceptor();
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> ris = new ArrayList<>();
    ris.add(ri);
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(ris);
    HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
    ResponseEntity<LocationIQResponse> response = null;
    LocationIQResponse obj = null;
    try {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(LOCATIONIQ_URL);

        uriBuilder.addParameter("key", LOCATIONIQ_TOKEN);
        uriBuilder.addParameter("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
        uriBuilder.addParameter("lon", String.valueOf(lng));
        uriBuilder.addParameter("format", "json");
        uriBuilder.addParameter("accept-language", "es");
        long delay = 100;
        boolean retry = true;
        do {
            try {
                long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                response = restTemplate.exchange(uriBuilder.build(), HttpMethod.GET, request,
                        LocationIQResponse.class);
                CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, ELAPSED, (double) (System.currentTimeMillis() - start));
                obj = response.getBody();
            } catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Problem input: {0},{1}", new Object[] { lat, lng });
                HttpInputMessage msg = e.getHttpInputMessage();
                if (msg == null) {
                    LOG.severe("Null response body");
                } else {
                    LOG.severe("Not null response body");
                    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(msg.getBody())) {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "HTTP Body: {0}", scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").next());
                    }
                }
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "cause");
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMostSpecificCause().getMessage());
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "exception");
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
                retry = false;
            } catch (HttpServerErrorException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage() + " / " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
                CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, SERVER_ERROR, 1);
                retry = false;
            } catch (ResourceAccessException e) {
                LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage());
                CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, SERVER_ERROR, 1);
                retry = false;
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
                String err = e.getResponseBodyAsString();
                if (HttpStatus.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS.equals(e.getStatusCode())) {
                    if (err.contains(RATE_LIMITED_SECOND)) {
                        CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, RETRIES, 1);
                        try {
                            Thread.sleep(delay);
                            delay *= 2;
                        } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    } else {
                        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, err);
                        CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, err, 1);
                        retry = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage() + " / " + err + " / " + e.getResponseBodyAsString());
                    CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, CLIENT_ERROR, 1);
                    retry = false;
                }
            } finally {
                CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(LOCATION_IQ, INVOCATIONS, 1);
            }
        } while (obj == null && retry);

        StackTraceElement elem = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[2];
        StackTraceElement elem2 = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
        CloudWatchSubmit.sendMetric(elem.getClassName(), elem.getMethodName(), elem2.getClassName(),
                elem2.getMethodName(), cached);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "Big Problem input: {0},{1}", new Object[] { lat, lng });
        LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return getAddress(obj);
}
```

After several invocations of the corresponding Lambda, we ocasionally get errors like:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/task/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/document/Table.class (Too many open files)
```

On another lambda using this same method we get the same Exception, but regarding log4j classes so, we are pretty sure it has to do with the referenced Java method, as it's opening HTTP connections (which correlate to file descriptors in Linux) via Spring's RestTemplate.

I've already read several posts and blogs regarding this issue on several environment where you can actually tweak the OS limits but, as we are inside an AWS Lambda the scenario is a bit different and I'd like recommendations on how to deal with this issue as, I'm trying to reproduce this issue outside Lambda and, haven't been able to do so. The idea was to get the same exception so check how several suggested changes may impact, either correcting the issue or, making it worse. But, as we haven't been able to reproduce it outside locally, we'll have to to trial and error on AWS Lambda execution environment.

Comment: Sorry I don't have anything to add. But I have the exact same problem with one of our Java lambda's. It appears that java is lazy loading the class files and sometimes it just doesn't have the FD left over to do so. Lambda has a limit of 1024 FDs so it doesn't take long to run out.

Comment: @klyd we discovered that we where leaving unclosed HTTP connections in a while loop and, since almost everything in Linux is backed by an FD, that was exhausting the limits.